# how to make yeoman create files in specific folder

Tags: yeoman

Im using a angular generator for yeoman and currently the default behavior is when I do

```
yo angular:controller testController
```

I have 2 files created

```
create app\scripts\controllers\testcontroller.js
create test\spec\controllers\testcontroller.js
```

say I want the **app**\ folder to be **www**\ is there a way I can configure yeoman to write the js file in a different directory?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it was designed to work that way.

However you can use grunt-contrib-copy to copy your file from app/ to www/.